# -webkit-appearance in bootstrap, how to reset?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I included Bootstrap to my project and whenever I inspect (in Google Chrome) an `<input type="submit">` tag, I see the following CSS on it:

```
button, html input[type=button], input[type=reset], input[type=submit]
{
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

From a stylesheet called normalize.less (never seen this before either).

According to the [documentation on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_appearance.asp) the default value would be `normal`, however when I put this property (`-webkit-appearance: normal`) inside my own custom stylesheet to override bootstrap, Google Chrome seems to not recognize the property (or the value assigned to the property). A yellow triangle in front of the property appears with the following message: "invalid property value".

Can anyone please explain me how this works? How can I reset this property on my tag so that it looks well again?

**Edit:** This is an example of what I want to achieve:
https://jsfiddle.net/86s9yLz3/

I want my button look like the first result and not like the second result (which is how it looks like right now, not the exact same, but due to the property (described earlier, the `-webkit-appearance` property) `height` changes and some other stuff like `line-height` or something...). When I use `-webkit-appearance: none;` or `-webkit-appearance: initial;`, the button doesn't like the third result in the JsFiddle either, instead it looks like this:

[image: submit button]

Comment: please don't use W3Schools and refer to MDN instead. Try with default value: `none` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance)

Comment: @LorenzoMarcon Ah allright thanks (your link is Spanish though).

Comment: uhm actually the url contains en-US.. maybe you got automatic translation in your language?

Comment: Sorry, it's my link in my answer that is in spanish. I edit right now.

Answer (score 6):

Your desired value is `none`:

```
 -webkit-appearance: none;
```

Use MDN instead (I can't see `normal` property here)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance

Comment: Wouldn't initial be better in case default none changes in the future?

Comment: Why it would change? If you use initial, in mobile devices you'll see the default appearance, but OP seems to need remove that appearance, so `none`  is the correct value.

Comment: The default (i.e. initial) appearance is none. If the user-agent styles change from none to something else in the future, the initial value would accommodate that.

Comment: You are wrong, initial value can be `none`, but mobile devices overrides it to put form items with the device appearance. Read carefully MDN: `Initial value none (but this value is overriden in the user agent CSS)`

Comment: This is actually not entirely what I wanted. Whenever I use the `<input type="submit>"` tag, I want to make it look like the way it would look like when there is not a single rule of styling on it. It would still appear as a button in Google Chrome. Then what is the default value for this property? The ` -webkit-appearance: none;` rule removes the entire button-ish look.

Comment: @Barrosy according with your comment, you'll have that property yet in your reset `-webkit-appearance: button`. With that, it appears as a button.

Comment: Seems like I cannot edit my last comment, but what I actually meant: "I would want it to still appear as a button in Google Chrome." The problem with the property is that it changes the height and other stuff of the button somehow...

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand what you need. With `webkit-appearance: button` it shows like a button. Maybe you need to remove that property in your reset and nothing more.

Comment: I guess that's my last option then. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry for can't help you better. Good luck :)